# Batch to start DOS app and then type things to it?

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003

I have a proprietary command line exe that prompts for username and password. Unfortunately it doesn't accept command line arguments for these. I need to make a batch file that will start the exe then type "user" then type "pass" and have it actually go to the stdin of the exe. This is on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Does the program request anything else from the user (from the standard input)?

Comment: Yes. I have to say "Yes" 3 times.

Comment: Right now I have a vb script that types what I specify into whatever the active window is. It's working, but man...

Comment: In that case my suggestion should be extended by including `ECHO Yes` three times. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
(ECHO username& ECHO password) | yourprogram.exe
```

That is, if I understood your situation right.

Note the absence of a space before `&`.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your reply to my comment, the above suggestion should probably be extended like this:

```
(ECHO username& ECHO password& ECHO Yes& ECHO Yes& ECHO Yes) | yourprogram.exe
```

Comment: i think this is sending "username\rpassword\ryes" into the first prompt.